# How to show images on the DOM as they come in using Jquery after the DOM has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am trying to add a template to the DOM using jquery. I wait for all the images to be loaded on the DOM, then grab all the images in a particular div, add a template to the DOM(which is a two card grid), and then use .each to loop over all those images and append them using the template to create multiple two card grids.

The issue is that it doesn't show up on the DOM.

Here is the code below:

```
 <script>
     function moveImages() {
       var $gallery = $('#gallery');
       // The template below will only have a 2 card grid. Hence an img counter.
       var imgcount = 1;
       // Initializing section counter for the 2 card grid. When img counter = 2, we increment it below so that we can have a new section ID to 
       // append the next two images one by one.
         var sectioncount = 0;
  
         //Here is the HTMl template, as the imgcount crosses 2, we create a new section. notice the dynamic variable below for sectioncount.
         var template = `<section class="card-grid-section section-${sectioncount}" loading="lazy">
         <a class="card-grid-two-image">
       <div>
         <picture id="card-one-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}">
         </picture>
       </div>
     </a>
     <a class="card-grid-two-image">
       <div>
         <picture id="card-two-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}">
         </picture>
       </div>
     </a>
     </section>`;
     
     //getting the html for the article-text id above.
       var test = $('#article-text').find('p').each(function(index, value) {
  
         //looping over all the children of each p tag below which are mostly span and img
         var children = value.childNodes;
         children.forEach(function(item, index1){
     
           // if the tag is a span, then we append it to the div with id gallery.
           if(item.tagName == "SPAN"){
             $gallery.append(`<p><span>${item.innerHTML}<span></p>`);
             console.log("ADDED SPAN TO GALLERY");
           }
  
           //if tag is an img
           else if(item.tagName == "IMG"){
             //I want to skip the first image here
             if(imgcount > 0){
             if(imgcount == 1){
               //appending the template to gallery only if imagecount = 1.
              $gallery.append(template);
               //item here, is an image. I am adding the first image to the card one of the first grid(template). Notice the sectioncount dynamic variable below.
               var $card1 = $(`#card-one-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}`);
               //Appending image to card one
               $card1.append(item);
             } else if(imgcount == 2){
               //if image count is 2, we are adding the the second image to template we created above.
               var $card2 = $(`#card-two-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}`);
               $card2.append(item);
               //Since image count is 2, we want a new grid id. Hence the sectioncount++.
                sectioncount++;
                //since we can only add two images to grid. I am setting imgcount back to 0;
                imgcount = 0;
             } 
             }
             //Incrementing img count below.
             imgcount++;
             }
           });
     });
     
       }
     
     $(document).ready(function($) {
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet with html as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write something like this:

```js
function gridTemplate(section) {
  return $(`<section class="card-grid-section section-${section}" loading="lazy">
    <a class="card-grid-two-image">
      <div>
        <picture id="card-one-two-grid-section-${section}"></picture>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="card-grid-two-image">
      <div>
        <picture id="card-two-two-grid-section-${section}"></picture>
      </div>
    </a>
  </section>`);
}
  
$(function () {
  var imgcount = 1, sectioncount = 0;

  $('#article-text p > *').each(function () {
    if (this.tagName === "SPAN") {
      $('#gallery').append(`<p><span>${this.innerHTML}<span></p>`);
    } else if (this.tagName === "IMG") {
      if (imgcount == 1) {
        $('#gallery').append(gridTemplate(sectioncount));
        $(`#card-one-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}`).append(this);
        imgcount++;
      } else {
        $(`#card-two-two-grid-section-${sectioncount}`).append(this);
        sectioncount++;
        imgcount--;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

(You really should cut back on the comments that say exactly what the code says - they are hugely distracting.)